# JUnit exception test fails (unexpectedly)

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit

I'm trying to run a JUnit test to test a method that will throw an exception. However, the test fails and I have no clue as to why it fails. The method that throws the exception is: calcultor.setN( );. I made two versions of this test, both of them fail even though they should pass.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();    

@Test
public void testSetNZero() {
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("Het aantal CPU's is minder dan 1");
    Amdahl calculator = new Amdahl();
    calculator.setN(0);
    fail("Exception not thrown");
}

@Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testSetNZero() {
    Amdahl calculator = new Amdahl();
    calculator.setN(0);
}
```

Amdahl class:

```
public class Amdahl 
{
    private int N;

    public void setN (int n) {
    if(n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Het aantal CPU's is minder dan 1");
    this.N = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `Amdahl` class

Comment: I have added the Amdahl class

Comment: What exception does this method throw? How `exception` is declared?

Comment: I added the rule where exception is declared.

Comment: It's indeed strange that they fail. I copy/pasted your code in my workspace and everything works just fine. What's the output message you get when the tests fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by using try-catch blocks whenever I expected an exception. If no exception or the wrong exception was present, the test fails.

```
@Test
public void testSetNZero() {
    Amdahl calculator = new Amdahl();
    try{
        calculator.setN(0);
        fail();
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`testSetNZero` fails because:

```
@Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testSetNZero() {
```

and

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
```

contradict each other and define a test that will always fail (it must both throw an exception and also not in order to pass). Use either `ExpectedException` *or* `@Test(expected = ...)`.

Comment: While testing, one of the methods as always commented out (including the rule when testing the @Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class) test.

Comment: You can use them both without the test failing.

Comment: Then please post the code you're actually running, along with the failure message. Also confirm that you're using a JUnit 4 test runner.